# How to delete PentextBox with Metasploit 2.3.exe

Tags: security, penetration-testing, penetration-tools

I have downloaded PentestBox with Metasploit 2.3.exe on my VM, this VM is important for testing so I cannot delete it all together, how can I delete the file. Any manipulation attempt towards the file is just not working (this includes copying, cut, paste, delete, move).

Please help

Regards